# How to remove menubar-button in PrimeReact's MenuBar?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, primereact

I want a [MenuBar](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/menubar) with no [hamburger button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlBuO.png) appearing while in responsive mode. I'm using CSS module to style my components. How can I completely remove hamburger menu button using CSS module? I can't find a way to access its specific HTML tag `<a class="p-menubar-button" ...>` and do `Display: None`.

MenuBar declaration in `NavBar.js` -

```
import { Menubar } from 'primereact/menubar'
import styles from './NavBar.module.css'

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Menubar start={start} end={end} className={styles.menubar} />
  )
}
```

CSS in `NavBar.module.css` -

```
.menubar {
  // I don't know how to access .p-menubar-button here
}
```

MenuBar component in plain HTML -

```
<div class="p-menubar p-component NavBar_menubar__ZntdZ">
  <div class="p-menubar-start">...</div>
  <a class="p-menubar-button" ...>...</a>
  <div class="p-menubar-end">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Shahriar I've added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is easy to solve using CSS's [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). I didn't know those selectors work with CSS module.

Here is the solution in `NavBar.module.css` -

```
.menubar > a[class="p-menubar-button"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```